# > Could not create task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:testReleaseUnitTest'. > this and base files have different roots:

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Even though I have deleted flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle from local disk d but still it is showing this error ->
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:test'.

> Could not create task ':flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle:testReleaseUnitTest'.
> this and base files have different roots: D:\book_store\build\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle and C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle-2.0.15\android.

I have tried

flutter clean

flutter pub get
in root directories

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to upgrade the Gradle version.

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
```